# Varnish: Cacheble but not cached

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

if i run this command

```
varnishtop -i txurl
```

that request is "cacheble" but not "cached". I see "Age=0" (age that is keep in varnish), how to edit it?

This is the request for my .php page

**GET -Used http://example.com**

```
User-Agent: lwp-request/5.810

200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 12:14:33 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 12:24:33 GMT
Client-Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 12:14:34 GMT
Client-Peer: 173.236.219.104:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cacheable: YES
X-Varnish: 840966561
```

**.htaccess code**

```
# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

**Default.vlc**

```
backend default {
    .host = "173.236.219.104";
    .port = "81";
     .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
        if (obj.hits > 0) {
                set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
        } else {
                set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }
}

sub vcl_fetch {

    # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";

    # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
    } elsif (req.http.Cookie ~ "(UserID|_session)") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
        return(hit_for_pass);

    # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
        return(hit_for_pass);

    # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
    } else {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    }

    # ....

    return(deliver);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add also the varnish config ? Only the relevant parts. Because this sounds a lot like a varnish config problem.

Comment: Could you please run varnishlog and then run GET -Used http://example.com or curl -I http://example.com/ and then paste the varnishlog output here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the backend gives back a cookie, therefore varnish does not cache the content.

Here more info about it: [Varnish-Cookies](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/cookies.html)

There are also some inconsistencies on the response you get from LWP.
In fact I see a max-age header set to 60 seconds, which I do not see configured on the backed end anywhere.

An LWP request to the origin as well, could help to debug the problem.